# Create multiple Entry boxes in a loop tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was making an application using tkinter and came across an error. I wanted people to input a variable, which I have made, and then have that many Entry boxes popup on the screen for input. I was wondering what is wrong with my code, if it is possible, or if there is a better way. Thanks in advance!

p.s. the NoOfBoxes has been predefined

```
    int(NoOfBoxes)
    x = 1
    while(NoOfBoxes>=x):
        a = a + 50
        fill_empty(a)
        x = x + 1

    def fill_empty():
        empty = tk.Entry(self)
        empty.grid(row=200,column=a)
        return empty
```

Comment: Your code does not create any Entry boxes. There is not even the word "Entry" in it. What did you expect?

Comment: OMG I feel so dumb. I changed this though and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In first line of shown code, you are converting `NoOfBoxes` to an integer but you are not assigning back it to `NoOfBoxes` hence, when `while` line comes, `NoOfBoxes` is still not an integer. Also, there is no parameter on your `fill_empty` definition.

Most likely you will need those Entry widgets at some point in your code, so it'll be much better if you keep references.

```
listOfEntries = [fill_empty(idx) for idx in range(int(NoOfBoxes))]

def fill_empty(a):
    empty = tk.Entry(self)
    empty.grid(row=200,column=a)
    return empty
```

When you want to make any operation on those, you can easily do something like:

```
listOfEntries[0].get()
```